# How to Add Cross-Compile Support for Rust on Offline System *without*Rustup

Tags: rust, cross-platform, cross-compiling, rust-cargo, rustup

I installed Rust on an offline system via an offline installer. Howbeit, this offline installer does not include rustup and I only know how to cross-compile using rustup commands.

Moreover, I was wondering how to add a target and cross-compile without rustup, if it’s even possible. I can drop files to the offline system but the system *cannot* be online. If there’s an offline way of adding rustup, I would accept that as an answer as well. Thanks!

Comment: Well, the point of rustup is to manage different toolchains for doing things like cross compiling. Without it, you'll have to find an alternate "offline installer" for the target you need.